# Git: putting a new branch in the middle of two existing branches

Tags: git, version-control, branch

A Git question:

A few months ago I branched `master` into new branch `devel` to test there new features.

Now I want make a "pre-release" (something middle between a release which is constituted by any commit into `master` and of `devel` rough draft). Let's call this branch `prerelease`. (I have not yet created this branch.)

How to add a branch BETWEEN two existing branches? That is I want to restructure `prerelease` as a branch of `master` and `devel` in turn as a branch of `prerelease`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git checkout -b prerelease sha1_number`

sha1_numer  represent the start_pointer commit you want to create branch prerelease.

Comment: Sorry, wrong: It should be `master` not `HEAD`. Will `git checkout -b prerelease master` work?

Comment: @porton, master is a branch name, a valid start pointer, I think it works when you start your new branch start from master branch.